# Segmentation fault while sorting the vector based on ordering induced by a matrix

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have written code which is like the follwing. I get segmentation fault error. The debugger shows  that the error is coming from 'some_order'. I checked the values of the variable for one particular example. Take n = 26: Then, Var  = {0,...,25} which means the u and v passed to 'some_order' must from the range (0-25) but I get some large value for one of them like 7785654 or -1549259 (somehting like that). I don't understand why. Segementation fault is then inevitable.

```
//TNT: template numeric toolkit
#include "tnt.h"  
//contains includes to all files in http://math.nist.gov/tnt/tnt_doxygen/files.html
//all other necessary stl and standard c++ libaray includes are there     

class global_data{
public:
  static TNT::Matrix<double>* Value_matrix;

};
TNT::Matrix<double>* global_data::Value_matrix = NULL;


bool some_order(const int& u ,const int& v) {
      return (*global_Data::Value_matrix)[v][u] == 0.0;
}

void some_function(int n){
    std::vector<int> Var(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        Var[i] = i;
    }
    std::sort(Var.begin(), Var.end(), some_order );
}

int main(){
    //assume we have n;       
    //nxn matrix, initialised with 0.0 
    global_data::Value_matrix = new TNT::Matrix<double>(n,n,0.0) ;
    //global_data::Value_matrix is then filled with values
    some_function(n); 
    delete[] global_data::Value_matrix
}
```

Comment: Your sort function is supposed to return which of the two parameters is larger, and it appears to do nothing of the kind.

Comment: your `some_function` does nothing observable. It creates a vector and sorts its, then throws it away.

Comment: @jcoder : This is different kind of sorting based on value of Value_matrix

Comment: @TemplateRex I have not posted the entire code, which is irrelevenat. there are further codes below it.

Comment: I think you didn't post some part of code, which is crucial to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: @UtkristAdhikari can you post a working example where we can re-generate the error ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of error is almost always due to the ordering function
not meeting the requirements of a strict weak ordering, as
required by the standard.  Are you sure that 1) `some_order(a,
b) && some_order(b, c)` implies `some_order(a, c)`, and that 2)
`some_order( a, b )` implies `!some_order(b, a)`?  (Off hand, it
doesn't look lke it to me, but I don't really understand what it
is doing.)

Comment: +1 In this test case, it would seem it always returns `true`, which would mean all elements should come before all others.

Comment: This might be the possible cause. I'll look into this matter.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson More importantly, that would mean that `a < b` and `b < a`, which violates the requirements for a strict weak ordering.  (Some implementations will actually detect this at run-time.)

Answer (score 5):

`std::sort` assumes that the comparison function models a [**Strict Weak Ordering**](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html)

- irreflexive: `some_order(u, u)` returns `false`
- anti-symmetric: `some_order(u, v)` implies `!some_order(v, u)` (both could be false, in which case `u` and `v` are equivalent)
- transitive: `some_order(u, v) == true` and `some_order(v, w) == true` implies `some_order(u, w) == true`

It would depend on the contents of your `global_Data` matrix whether your `some_order()` can be used with `std::sort`

```
- irreflexive: diagonal cannot have 0.0 on it
- anti-symmetric: if an entry has 0.0 then the transpose element has no 0.0
- transitive: if `global_Data[u, v]` and `global_Data[v, w]` have 0.0 then `global_Data[u, w]` also has that.
```

A priori it seems a very strong restriction, you might want to check it.

Comment: Your second condition is wrong: `some_order(u, v)` implies `!some_order(v, u)`, but both can be false (and `!some_order(u, v) && !some_order(v, u)` defines an equivalence relationship).

Comment: the std::sort will not use some_order(u, u) right? why would an element be compared with iteself while sorting. Is is just the part of definition of strict weak ordering

Comment: @JamesKanze tnx, fixed!

Comment: @UtkristAdhikari no, `std::sort` would not compare an element with itself. the condition is part of the def. of SWO, in particular comparison of equivalent elements should yield `false`.

Comment: @UtkristAdhikari It depends on the implementation of `std::sort`.  Many quick sort implementations _do_ compare an object with itself; it's often cheaper and simpler to do that than to add an additional condition in one of the innermost loops.

Comment: @UtkristAdhikari And of course, the sequence may contain multiple objects with the same value (or in the same equivalence class).